# Does XForms support locking parts of a form?

Tags: locking, xforms

Does XForms support any kind of locking? For example, could I create a form with it, that is divided into sections, and use and id on each section to do optimistic locking just for a particular section?

Does a XForms have built in support for locking, or is this something I would have to add myself?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "optimistic locking" is a term about databases, not user interfaces. What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: "optimistic locking" probably is a database term, although it extends into UI design too, inevitably. For example, do you design a UI that requires users to explicitly lock items for edit, or implicitly lock items by making use of a version stamp in the database to detect concurrent edits?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do:

I have a large form, which can be edited by multiple users at once. The form is divided into sections, with one section corresponding to one page on the UI. The sections can only be edited by one user at a time, and we plan to use optimistic locking at the section level to enforce this.

Comment: When a section is submitted, it would be helpful to pull back the other sections with any updates made to them by other users at that time, so that when the page is refreshed summary information about the other sections can also be updated.

It is possible in the future that we might want a different locking scheme. For example, users must explicitly lock a section, or concurrent updates are allowed, and we will automatically merge changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can "lock" parts of your form using the [**`readonly property`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#model-prop-readOnly) that's part of the [**`model item properties`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#model).